# LR test on marginal effect

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, likelihood-ratio

Say I have the following regression model:

$$\text{Wage}_i = constant + α·\text{YearsOfEduc}_i + β·\text{Age}_i + γ·\text{CompletedHighSchool}_i + \mbox{δ·$\text{NumOfSiblings}_i$} + ε·\text{Gender}_i + u_i$$

How would I perform an LR test of the hypothesis that the **marginal effect of age on the wage** for

- a male,
- has two siblings,
- who completed high school,
- has 3 years of education

... is the **same as** for:

- a female,
- has one sibling,
- who completed high school,
- has 3 years of education.

I can modify the model above if needed, but what would be my unrestricted and restricted models, and how would I use them in a regression?

Comment: The answer is the same as in the previous question you asked: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115871 So, what did you not understand about the previous answer?

Comment: I understand the previous answer... but what I don't get about this is now I'm comparing a male who has median siblings vs a female with 1 sibling. So I'm not sure how I would get my UR and R models

Answer (score 1):

Since you are conditioning on a number of variables, what you seem to want is a mixture of a marginal and a conditional (adjusted) effect of sex.  I would not know how to interpret such an estimate, as it can be manipulated by oversampling males according to the number of siblings he has, when obtaining the data.  You might consider a sequence of conditional estimates.  Here is an example in R for a model with three predictors: sex, sibs, and age, with age and number of sibs not assumed to operate linearly.

```
require(rms)
n <- 100; set.seed(1)
sex <- sample(c('female', 'male'), n, TRUE)
sibs <- sample(0:7, n, TRUE)
age <- rnorm(n, 40, 10)
dd <- datadist(sex, sibs, age); options(datadist='dd')
y <- 3*(sex == 'male') + sibs + .01*(age - 40)^2 + rnorm(n, 0, 4)

f <- ols(y ~ sex + pol(sibs, 2) + rcs(age, 5))
coef(f)['sex=male']  # 2.744
contrast(f, list(sex='male', sibs=0:5),
            list(sex='female', sibs=1))

   sibs Contrast      S.E.      Lower    Upper    t Pr(>|t|)
      0 1.843579 0.9748423 -0.0925419 3.779700 1.89   0.0617
      1 2.743908 0.9072221  0.9420867 4.545730 3.02   0.0032
      2 3.694806 1.0995190  1.5110664 5.878546 3.36   0.0011
*     3 4.696273 1.2790347  2.1559993 7.236546 3.67   0.0004
*     4 5.748308 1.3630204  3.0412318 8.455384 4.22   0.0001
*     5 6.850912 1.3617277  4.1464032 9.555421 5.03   0.0000

Redundant contrasts are denoted by *

Error d.f.= 92 

Confidence intervals are 0.95 individual intervals
```

Note that when sibs=1 for a male the contrast 2.744 equals the regression coefficient for sex.

If you really want, you can get a weighted average of the conditional estimates according to some reasonable external distribution of sibs to marginalize on sibs.  This can be done by specifying `type='average', weights=...` to `contrast`.  But I would not recommend marginalization.

Comment: I don't really understand this

Comment: Are you understanding what the contrasts are estimating?  These are very well-defined conditional quantities.  Are you just not understanding why one might do it this way?  Please elaborate.

Comment: This is really beyond me. I have no idea what contrasts and conditional quantities are. All I want to do is a Likelihood Ratio test for the above, and I'm stuck determining the Unrestricted and Restricted model.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, a likelihood ratio test assumes that you have a very specific hypothesis, and your hypothesis is not well-defined because of incomplete conditioning.  There is no unrestricted model for one sex that effectively removes a covariate from the entire modeling process.  My suggestion is to work with a statistician.

Comment: I have updated the conditioning to make it more clearer. Each variable has a conditional value for both cases. Does this help in constructing a UR/R model?

Comment: That is very clear.  We need to note that my answer above was to your original question where sibs was not specified for males.  You get what you now want by looking at the 3rd line (sibs=2) of the table I produced.  3.69 is the estimate of the difference in means between the sexes for a male with 2 sibs and a female with 1.  It is not at all easy to do this with a likelihood ratio test.  But in the Gaussian linear model the Wald test is exact.  Don't think of restricted and unrestricted models; just think of which conditions you want to compare and compute the contrast that does that.

Comment: Ok, but the restricted and unrestricted models are what I am really looking for in asking the question... so could you please answer to that...

Comment: Also what is the null hypothesis?

Comment: You are forcing the use of the LR test in a situation for which it is not well suited.  LR tests are especially useful for the case when $H_{0}$ can be represented by a restriction on a model, and you end up comparing the restricted and unrestricted model.  The restricted model is a smaller model nested inside the full model.  You do not have have nested models here; both models have the same number of parameters.  $H_{0}$ is the hypothesis that the mean wage for a male with 2 sibs is the same as the mean wage for a female with 1 sib, other covariates remaining equal.